# Чи існує слово "мому"?

Tags: вживання-слів, існування-слова

Кілька разів чула, що кажуть слово "мому", а не "моєму". І переважно це стосується жителів таких міст як Львів та Тернопіль. Це діалект?

Answer (score 4):

Існує і є «народнім говором» (по-суті, діялект), згадане наприклад мовознавцем [Синявським](//r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/slovozmina_zaymennyk):

> 2. Поруч наведених загальнолітературних форм різних займенників по народніх говорах живуть іще різноманітні варіянти їх, і їх частенько подибуємо в поезії, напр.:
>
>    > мого, твого, свого – мойого, твойого, свойого
>    >
>    > моєму, твоєму, своєму – мойому, мойму, **мому**…